# how to make default route login in laravel 6

Tags: laravel, authentication

when I want to enter the address `http://localhost/agendab/public/` it gives me `404 Not Found`, because no have a route, and for me I want to be logged in on the 1st page to navigate.
**web.php**

```
Auth::routes();
Route::resource('events', 'EventController')->middleware('auth');
```

Comment: why `/agendab/public/` ? why don't `http://localhost/` ?

Comment: Edit the Auth routes?

Comment: @geertjanknapen thx for u answer ,you can tell me how i edit Auth routes ?